# How to retrieve individual tile images using Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps, rest

Using the Google Maps Static Map API, I'm able to enter a location and retrieve a single composited image at a specified zoom level.

I'm interested in adding a dynamic scrolling/zooming interface — how can I use the Google Maps API to retrieve individual map tile images around a specified location and zoom level?

For example, if I use a DOM inspector when visiting http://maps.google.com/, I can pick out a 256x256 tile image such as this:

[image: https://mts1.google.com/vt/x=2227&y=3120&z=13]

https://mts1.google.com/vt/x=2227&y=3120&z=13

How can I calculate values for the `x` and `y` parameters in that URL?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is, you shouldn't.  [From the FAQ](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq):

> **Can I access the Maps and Satellite images directly?**
>
> You may not
>   access the maps or satellite images through any mechanism besides the
>   Google Maps APIs (such as the creation of your own mapping API or the
>   use of a bulk tile download script). Your application's access to the
>   tiles will be blocked if it accesses them outside of the Google Maps
>   APIs. See section 10.1.1.a of the Google Maps Terms of Service for
>   more details.

And in case the threat of getting blocked isn't enough, any system you come up with yourself will sooner or later break when Google changes the internal URL without warning.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following java code:-

```
String temp;
Image image = null;
temp="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="+latitude+","+longitude+"& zoom=18&size=100x100&sensor=false&maptype=satellite";
URL url = new URL(temp);
image = ImageIO.read(url);
ImageIO.write((RenderedImage) image, "jpg",new File("D:\\map.jpg"));

// give the latitude and the longitude as 25.165173,47.237548
```

And run the code you will the image of  an area in Saudi Arabia.

I think it would be useful.

Comment: Thanks, but, as I said, I'm familiar with the basic Google Maps Static Map API for retrieving a composited image, which is what your answer demonstrates.  My question is asking how to retrieve the underlying tiles, not a composited image.

Comment: What do you mean by underlying tile?

Comment: When you visit maps.google.com, the main map viewport is made up of a bunch of smaller 256x256 square tiles — you can see the tile images flicker into place as they are loaded.  Those are the underlying tiles I'm referring to.

Comment: This tiles can be retrieved through the static map API by giving the specified latitude and the longitude and the zoom level. What is wrong with this? Why are you not considering this as the tiles? Please explain.. as i am doing a project using this concept.

Answer (score 1):

Must you use Google Maps?  OpenStreetMap, http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles, might have more lenient terms of service and be easier to query for the tiles.